# Dropdown not fully visible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image: Dropdown]

Unfortunately, the content of the dropdown gets cut.

What's the Twitter Bootstrap-way to achieve that the menu opens to the left side instead of the right (without manual CSS hacks)?

```
<div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Developer <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Generate dummy data</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="btn">Edit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the class `pull-right` to the dropdown menu like this :

Jsfiddle [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/GYBYT/show/)

```
<div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
<div class="btn-group open">
    <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle">
        Developer <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right"><!-- this is where pull-right is applied-->
        <li>
            <a href="#">Generate dummy data</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
<button class="btn">Edit</button>
```